# Can I determine the maximum acceleration with frequency and magnitude?

Tags: harmonic-oscillator

Consider a mass oscillating up and down on a spring with negligible energy loss.
If only the frequency and magnitude of the oscillation is known, how can one determine the maximum acceleration of the mass?

Comment: What have you tried? Write down the position versus time for the oscillator. Then write down the definition of acceleration. I bet you can answer your question now.

Comment: I tried, I took the derivative of position over time to yield velocity over time. I guessed and checked to find that the maximum velocity is 2π*f*A; where f is frequency and A is amplitude, but I don't understand what I did or how to get further.

Comment: The time derivative of position is velocity.  The time derivative of velocity is...

Comment: Write down what you did in your post (you can use the "edit" button), and then also put the definition of acceleration. I bet you can figure it out now.

Comment: Tell me if this is correct:

x=f(t)=sin(t+φ) * A

v=f'(t)=cos(t+φ) * A

a=f''(t)=-sin(t+φ) * A

Comment: @DanielSank
Okay, just a moment.

Comment: The equations in the comment two above this one are missing the frequency inside the $\sin$ and $\cos$ functions!

Comment: That is right! How can I integrate frequency in them? Also, I get that velocity and acceleration can be expressed as general formula, but how can I find out the values of the maxima using frequency and amplitude?

Comment: Okay, I have been tinkering around, here is what I have:

f''(t)=A cos(f(t+φ)) - A f (t+φ) sin(f(t+φ))

Comment: The correct equation is $x(t) = A \cos(\omega t + \phi)$, or if you prefer regular frequency $f$ instead of angular frequency $\omega$, use $x(t) = A \cos(2 \pi f t + \phi)$. Now try taking some derivatives and all your problems will be solved :D